# Show PowerBi reports for guest users

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, powerbi

I need to develop an application with will show embedded reports from PowerBI for Guest users.
I can create a guest user in Azure Ad by invitation like this:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//invitations' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ....' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "oleksii@test.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://myapp.test.com"
}'
```

Bearer token for this call I generate by the next method:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=ClientId' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' \
--data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=/signin-oidc' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=ClientSecret'
```

In all examples for BowerBi using the default Microsoft Authentication UI and do login by email and password, like this [one](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/.NET%20Core/Embed%20for%20your%20organization/UserOwnsData).

But the guest user doesn't have a password and I can't change it by API.

How I can get an auth token to get all guest user reports from

Comment: Don't use `Embed for your organization/UserOwnsData`, but `Embed for your customers/AppOwnsData` and authenticate the guest users the way you want, before giving them access to the report.

Comment: Hi @AndreyNikolov,
I don't understand how a guest user can do authenticate, because it doesn't have a password and I can't manage that password in my web application

Comment: Just write a simple web app, with authentication, and place the reports there. The web pages will not be accessible without authentication, you can authorize different users of your app to access only some of the pages (i.e. some of the reports), etc. In other words, you will do the authorization and authentication, not Power BI or AAD.

Comment: Firstly, your method to get the token is client credentials flow, which doesn't require a user to sign in. But the sample requires a user to sign in. So in this case, you cannot use client credentials flow, but use auth code flow. Secondly, guest user indeed has a password. Generally, the guest user is a work account from other tenant or an MSA, both of the two user type have a password.

Comment: @OleksiiMykhniak Any updates?

Comment: @AllenWu Hi, I tried to use the next sample to get a report for guest users:
https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html
so I used code auth flow and then used auth token in JS demo, but it doesn’t work.

Comment: @What is the error now? Please provide more details.